# Install virtual environment and install cassandra-driver inside virtual environment using yml(ansible)

Tags: cassandra, ansible, devops, devops-services

I am learning ansible.

I want to install virtual environment and install cassandra-driver inside venv. Could some one suggest me how to do that?

here is the code I have tried.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  name: install cassendra-driver
  become: true
  become_user: root
  tasks:
       - name: Install the latest version of pip
         apt:
            name: python-pip
            state: latest
            force_apt_get: yes
       - name: Install virtualenv
         pip:
            name:
              - virtualenv
       - name: Install "cassandra-driver"
         pip:
          name:
              - cassandra-driver==3.19.0
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your playbook:

- you are installing pip and cassandra-driver on your local machine but you are trying to install them inside a virtual environment
- virtual environenments already contain pip so you don't need to install it

This should fix your issues:

```
tasks:
- name: Manually create the initial virtualenv
  command: python3 -m venv env
- name: Install "cassandra-driver"
  command: env/bin/python -m pip install cassandra-driver
```

Comment: Yes, I did. Output looks good. How to check whether venv installed or not? What is the location of venv installed?

Comment: Also could you please explain what's happening in above commands?

Comment: `python3 -m venv env` creates the environment `env`.

Comment: `env/bin/python -m pip install cassandra-driver` uses the generated environment (`env/bin/python`) to call the `pip` module using the arguments `install cassandra-driver`

Comment: Yes, Got it. Thank you